# Detecting Available Displays on an Android Device Using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

As you know, some phones have **external or secondary displays**, for example Motorola's new foldable Razr phones, or Samsung's Z Flip 3. I was wondering if there was a way to access those displays programmatically using Kotlin, or simply just verifying their presence.
The real reason I want information about this is because my Motorola Razr 2019 has an issue where the phone does not recognize the fold action, so the external display is never told to come on by the phone. **I decided to write an app that forces the external display to come on for that matter.** Any pointers would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually camera apps have a feature to use the rear camera for selfies. If that can turn on the display then you could write an app that runs on the secondary display. [More info about starting an activity on a specific display](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support#secondary_displays). But, being as the primary display would stay the same, I don't think you can force other apps to launch on the secondary display. My suggestion would be to start the device in safe mode and check if your issue persists.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, the razr 2019 also has that camera feature. That means the code of the motorola system camera app actually references the second display. When I iterate through the list of displays (displayManager.getDisplays()), though, I get only the main one. If I could get a hold of the second display's id, I'd proceed with the link you posted.

Comment: As for the safe mode, that does not help. I listed all sensors on this device and I am almost certain that the "Flip Position  Wakeup" sensor is not functional.

Comment: "I decided to write an app that forces the external display to come on for that matter" -- the OS handles displays; there are no APIs to "force" one "to come on". You would need to see if Lenovo has their own SDK for working with that secondary display. "When I iterate through the list of displays (displayManager.getDisplays()), though, I get only the main one" -- this is not surprising.